# "Cannot find entry point sqlite3_open_v2 in DLL sqlite3" when using System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I am having problems connecting to a Sqlite database through System.Data.Sqlite. I was trying to use FluentNhibernate but that didn't work, so I went back to basics but got the same error: Cannot find entry point sqlite3_open_v2 in DLL sqlite3.

This is my (fairly simple I believe) code:

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Stripper.s3db;Initial Catalog=main;"))
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from album", connection))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                object t = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

I have a reference to System.Data.SQLite so everything seems fine to me. The few explanations (you can barely call them tutorials) on the internet haven't helped me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be the version of Sqlite3 you are working against. The V2 methods are relatively new - [introduced in v3.5](http://www.sqlite.org/34to35.html)

Comment: Just had this same issue on winXP and resolved it by installing the latest version of sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible explanation is that you're using a 32 bit version of the provider in a 64 bit application.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded v1.0.60.0 from the System.Data.Sqlite website (sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) which leads to http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=132486. As you can see there isn't much choice, so I can't think I'm doing anything wrong there. If I am not mistaken, Sqlite3 is included in System.Data.Sqlite so one would expect it to be the good version.
I am definitely working with the 32bit version on a 32bit application.
I have downloaded the installer and will try with that (I was using the binaries).